# Can item-based collaborative filtering in mahout be evaluated at different neighborhoods?

Tags: java, mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender, collaborative-filtering

In user-based collaborative filtering with mahout, we can use such code to evaluate the results at different neighborhoods size

```
GenericUserBasedRecommender recommender = new GenericUserBasedRecommender(model, neighborhood, userSimilarity);
```

Is it possible in item-based CF with mahout to evaluate the results at different neighborhoods? The "GenericItemBasedRecommender" doesn't seems to have a neighborhood parameter. If that is not possible, then how to compare item-based CF with user-based CF?